# PHP build an array from a comma separated list

Tags: php

So basically I have a column in the database which has stored multiple values like this

```
0 , 33, 0, 0, 138, 1231
```

What i would like to do is build an array from the output obtained from the database:

```
$values = $fetch['values'];
```

Comment: `explode()`? And please do not tag unrelated products

Comment: MorganFreeFarm answered you question with an example, but you should really use a relational database model so that you wouldn't need to store values like you're doing right now.

Comment: There is some cases when you need to store data like this, but use json string. then you can easy get array from this string and string from the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$values = '0,33,0,0,138,1231';

$array = explode(',', $values);

var_dump($array);

?>
```

The output:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(2) ""0" [1]=> string(2) "33" [2]=> string(1) "0" [3]=> string(1) "0" [4]=> string(3) "138" [5]=> string(4) "1231" }
```

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.explode.php)

Comment: This did not work , it added all items to only 1 array column, array[0] only

Comment: @Gongas - it works for me. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Not an error it simply adds all the list to only 1 array column  , array(1) { [0]=> string(240) "0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,33,0" }

Comment: @B001ᛦ not a typo that was just an example for what i wanted,  im getting the values from a database column where i inserted them

Comment: It's not working , was due to fact the explode had an extra space after the " , "  which i did not have in my list so i removed the space and all was ok !